# How to determine the work items associated with a source branch in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I check in in my source code in the development branch against work items. All checkins are required to have an associated work item. So when I view history on the branch, I can see all of the work items associated with that branch.

In the meantime, I'm doing bug fixes in the current release branch. Also, those are associated with their own work items.

When the time comes for another release, we merge release to main to pick up production bug fixes, development to main to pick up the new functionality and then finally create a new release branch from main.

My question is, I want to be able to "View History" (or another command that will give me the data I want) on my new release branch and see the changesets that were associated the bug fixes in the last release build and the development branch that combined to make that release branch. Is there a way to do this?

Essentially we need a way to see what work items were resolved for a particular release branch. Also, we'd want to be able to search for a work item ID and see what release branch fixed it.

Sorry if this is unclear, I'm learning some of this as I go.

Comment: I think I know what you are asking but maybe a graphic would (ahem) illustrate your question better? A picture is worth a thousands words...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any command exists for this. The bestway is to use the Track Changeset feature in TFS2010. Check this MSDN library for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405662.aspx

In Track Changeset view, you can right click the Branch where changes originated and Click Changeset details which will open up the changeset details window. Here, you can check the associated workitems with that changes.

Comment: So there's no way to associate change sets with a new branch? What do people typically do to get visibility on what work items were resolved in a particular release?

Comment: When we create Workitems, we add the Release Name to the Area workitem Field drop-down and we assign all workitems of a particular release to Corresponding Release Name under Area field. Then, we use workitems queries (filtered by Area = Release Name) to find all the workitems in particular release.

Comment: Going to mark this as answer since your last comment helped to point me in the right direction! Thx.