# TFS Merge And Keep The Associated Changesets/Comments

Tags: tfs

So let's say I'm working in a development branch and I checked in a change, supplied a comment, and associated a work item.  Now I want to merge that back to Main, is there a way I can have TFS merge know to associate that same work item and comment by default when I attempt to check it in?

Seems trivial but scale this out to multiple changesets a day and recording the work item numbers to reselect gets very tedious...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TFS has in my opinion a weakness on this one. All TFS-guides out there suggest that a multiple-branch scheme should be applied - which is absolutely reasonable (see [here](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) for a great reference).
Developers shall be working in 'playground' branches & once tests have succeeded, changesets are propagated into moree stable - more Release-near branches.
A somewhat duplicate question on that is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536323/how-to-determine-the-work-items-fixed-in-a-particular-tfs-build-when-using-branc) one.
According to the answers, an [extension](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2011/05/17/automatically-merging-work-items-in-tfs-2010.aspx) by J.Ehn could do what you 're after on the link-to-WI aspect. No evidence shows that the add-comments aspect is somehow included - yet this might not make tremendous sense (what should happen if the merge contains multiple commits from the \DEV-branch?). Still, it should be possible to fork this implementation and add the comments as well.
 In the same question E.Blankenship provides with a rough road to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7577080/728929) alternative.

Comment: For the record, Ed's proposal wouldn't get me what I needed (I 'm focusing on Gated checkins) & and my company didn't have the courage to try out Jakob's solution (mgmnt felt this could damage our installation). So I'm still having this issue.

Answer (score 3):

In TFS, when you merge branches, the resulting Changeset is linked to all Changesets merged.

If you've merged a Changeset containing a file from Branch A to B, then in Branch B if you view history on that file it will show the Merge Changeset with a '+' next to it that allows you to tunnel to the original Changeset with comments and associated items.  Why doesn't this auditing trail fulfill your requirement?

Comment: Suppose you solve a Bug in the DEV branch & associate the commit with the Bug during check in. When you open the WI, you see this changeset. At some point this got merged into MAIN branch. But where? That's not in the WI. >> I think that's the issue here, it's an issue on my table as well.

Comment: So the issue isn't navigating via source control for auditing, but when navigating from WIs to Source Control.  I see.  In that case, you may be able to add a custom WIT field that helps track this using the WIT editor.  I'd have to mull that over some more.