# Merge in TFS 2012 and reuse comments and work items?

Tags: version-control, merge, visual-studio-2012

I want to merge a single changeset from a feature branch into the MAIN line. How can I easily reuse the text of the original checkin's comment and re-associate the original linked work items? Currently, I've to copy the text manually and look up the work item ID(s) by hand to use them for the merge checkin.

Are there any tools or option to influence this process?

Comment: It's a great question and it bugs the life out of me as this is one manual step we have trouble getting people to do consistently.

Comment: Why are you merging every individual changeset? If you are merging many changesets TFS takes care of rationalising the comments and changeset links internally in TFS 2010/2012...

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS Merge And Keep The Associated Changesets/Comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992090/tfs-merge-and-keep-the-associated-changesets-comments)

Answer (score 1):

This visual studio add in will do this [Auto Merge](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/de186cc3-0dd5-4100-bd2c-bdcd651ac4b4)