# TFS API 2010: Track a file across all branches

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

Using the TFS API I am trying to approximate bugs/file.

A bug (as I define it) originates from a file in a change set that has been associated with a work item that has type WorkItemType = 'Bug'. For example, in branch-a, branch-a/1.txt and branch-a/2.txt are checked in and associated with a 'Bug' work item. Call this changeset X. There are now two bugs in branch-a associated with those two files.

If I merge branch-a back into its parent (the root branch), the root also gains these bugs, so root/1.txt and root/2.txt are also bugs - basically the root branch has gained the buggy history of it child. Bugs can be inherited in this fashion. This property is preserved across renames. So if root/1.txt was renamed to root/hello.txt it's still a bug.

I start with iterating over all "Bug" work items in the TFS project:
In this example there is a single work item, which is associated with changeset X, which is associated with changes on branch-a/1.txt and branch-a/2.txt (although those files could be renamed now in the present).

Now I want to know all places where branch-a/1.txt and branch-a/2.txt ended up (once again, even with renames).

So, given a Changeset cs and a Change c within cs, I want know for each branch if c made it into that branch and the most recent file name where c resides.

Another way to think about the problem is thinking about moving forward through history. I start at specific point in time with a change in a single branch. Now this change needs to be tracked all the way to the present.

Any ideas? I can provide clarification as needed.

Thank you!

Comment: I made some code to track Work Items associated with a changeset - tracking from branched codelines. Maybe you can use this. It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8551150/600559

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried tracking the changeset?

View History on the file that has the change (1.txt) > Right Click on the changeset > Track Changeset > Check all visible > Visualize.

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but it might a good place to start.

Video that shows it: [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vn7hsiuO8b4)

Not sure if it's possible using the API. [This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/0b89e118-134e-448d-a749-3ac9ae226ea7) seems to suggest that it's not possible using API calls. [This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylaf/archive/2010/04/26/enable-visualization-and-changeset-tracking-for-branches-through-the-ui-and-programmatically.aspx) seems to suggest that it is possible.